# Rotating and Translating Objects

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to rotate and translate objects. I can make both, but after rotating orientation is lost -- objects move in the orientation they're facing.

```
        if( keyboard.pressed("up"))
            objects[movementControls.translate].translateX(1);
        if( keyboard.pressed("down"))
            objects[movementControls.translate].translateX(-1);
        if( keyboard.pressed("left"))
            objects[movementControls.translate].translateZ(-1);
        if( keyboard.pressed("right"))
            objects[movementControls.translate].translateZ(1);
        if( keyboard.pressed("x"))
            objects[movementControls.rotate].rotation.x+=0.1;
        if( keyboard.pressed("y"))
            objects[movementControls.rotate].rotation.y+=0.1;
        if( keyboard.pressed("z"))
            objects[movementControls.rotate].rotation.z+=0.1;
```

there is a way to rotate only the object and not the axes ?

Comment: All rotation and translation operations are applied around the origin (0,0,0). If you want to preserve translation when rotating, you need to save the current object position, translate the object first to (0,0,0), rotate, and then translate back. It might be worth looking into a [scene graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Scene_graph) to manage complex objects and scenes - one for WebGL is [SceneJS](http://scenejs.org/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add your object in an other parent object with `parent.add(yourobject);`. Then move the parent, rotate the child.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem, then you need to use `position.applyAxisAngle`  instead `rotation`: http://jsfiddle.net/my1bqtv8/